# Why my RUN has no effect on the docker image that is built?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dns

Here is the simple Dockerfile

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.19
RUN echo nameserver 10.0.0.1 > /etc/resolv.conf
RUN cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

I give this command:

```
docker build .
```

I get this output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.19
 ---> c39664f3d4e5
Step 2/3 : RUN echo nameserver 193.205.160.3 > /etc/resolv.conf
 ---> Running in ffa4ed664323
Removing intermediate container ffa4ed664323
 ---> 91d2456bb9d7
Step 3/3 : RUN cat /etc/resolv.conf
 ---> Running in cd6463980f69
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

# No DNS servers known.

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
Removing intermediate container cd6463980f69
 ---> 089e36d3d140
Successfully built 089e36d3d140
```

Clearly the file does not cotain the text I expected.

I'm sorry I'm new with Docker. Does somebody know what am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and I installed docker with snap.

Answer (score 1):

The `/etc/resolv.conf` file is managed by Docker and is injected into every container it starts. Each RUN line is executed in a new container. Therefore during the second RUN line, a new container is created, and a fresh copy of /etc/resolv.conf is injected into the container. To manage DNS in spawned containers there are several options:

1. `docker run --dns 10.0.0.1 your_image` will add the DNS entry to a single container
2. Adding `{ "dns": ["10.0.0.1"] }` to the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and restarting the docker engine (typically with `systemctl restart docker`) will set the new default for all docker containers, and can be overridden with the above option.
3. Updating the host `/etc/resolv.conf` will affect containers it starts assuming one of the above has not been done.

Disclaimer, the second and third options apply to docker installed on the host, and a snap based install could impact them.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explaination. 
None of the 3 options is applicable in my case.

1. I need the DNS to work during the build phase, since subsequent steps require apt to install packages. 

2.I did that, but it does not work.

3. I read that resolv.conf is injected based on the one from the host machine: in my case this does not happen.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/issues/2187
This issue describes the problem that I'm experiencing.

It looks like that the solution to my problem could be prepending "echo nameserver 193.205.160.3 > /etc/resolv.conf && " to every RUN command that needs internet access. At least until somebody fixes the problem.

Comment: @vvigilante I'm fairly certain that the issue with 2 and 3 for you is because of the snap layer of isolation. See the following issue on snap for how to update the daemon.json there, but realize this setting needs to be reapplied after every update. You may find it easier to manage docker when it's installed directly on the host. https://github.com/docker/docker-snap/issues/22

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure, but are there Quotation marks missing?

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.19
RUN echo 'nameserver 10.0.0.1' > /etc/resolv.conf
RUN cat /etc/resolv.conf
```